# как сэмитировать нажате на enter через консоль?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть input type = textarea, я изменяю value через консоль, как сэмитировать нажатие на клавишу enter через консоль что бы сработала отправка сообщения?

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, зачем тебе это нужно?

Comment: в некоторых случаях работает добавление символа '\n' в конец строки

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев пентагон взламываю

Comment: @eSkry есть ещё варианты?

Comment: Попробуй прибавить к содержимому String.fromCharCode(13)

Comment: Попробуй dispatchEvent

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется самое простое решение - имитация клика:

```
document.querySelector('button.my-button').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

ну как вариант можно так:

```js
function checkKey(e) {
  var inp = document.getElementById('inp1');
  if(e.keyCode == "13") {
    document.getElementById('d').innerText = inp.value;
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="inp1" onkeydown="checkKey(event)" id="inp1" />
<div id="d"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ke = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13
});
document.body.dispatchEvent(ke);
```

Answer (score -2):

`input.value += "\n"` в данном случае input  это наша textarea

Comment: Ни один метод не сработал